# Is v-bind called when referencing a component in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an upload component that submits after a message has been sent. In that component I have an `action` that states the request URL which is `v-bind`ed. However, every time I call the reference, the `v-bind` seems to not trigger and just gives me a blank. I'm using Element UI btw.

**HTML**

```
<el-upload :action="latestMessageAttachmentUrl" ref="uploadFiles"></el-upload>
```

**JS**

```
submitMessage () {
  // Submit data to server
  return api.createMessage( messageToSend, ( message ) => {
    this.latestMessageAttachmentUrl = './messages/' + message.id + '/attachments';
    this.$refs.uploadFiles.submit();
  } );
}
```

Comment: is `latestMessageAttachmentUrl` defined in your `data` section?

Comment: yes sir it's defined

Comment: Possibly you need to put the submit call in [nextTick](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Vue does not update View right update when data changes so you should submit in `nextTick`

```
submitMessage () {
  // Submit data to server
  return api.createMessage( messageToSend, ( message ) => {
    this.latestMessageAttachmentUrl = './messages/' + message.id + '/attachments';
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.$refs.uploadFiles.submit();
    })
  } );
}
```